Recharts disable animation when refreshing the data
I am currently using an area chart from Recharts which i like very much. It animates when I load the page and looks very nice.
However, bec my data is live, I refetch updated data from the database every 30 seconds but I don't want the chart to animate again every 30 seconds. I only want it to animate on page load. How can I accomplish this?
